# Java Applet File Upload not Using HttpCleints

Tags: java, http

I want to upload multiple files using Java Applets.

I developed an working application using Apache Http Client.

The issue with above is applet dependency as a Jar(s) for Apache Http Client.

Currently , I need to import / download 7 jars file for only one small feature [File Upload].

in the production environments it increases downloading time very much.

So i want a simple library or Java Class by which we can upload multiple files using HTTP protocol and can get a simple response.

i found so many codes on the internet and so , but with them problem starts with binary upload.

For example ,
  if we upload a wave file using simple upload , after uploading when we listen it at server side , it is distorted.

if we upload a JPEG file using simple upload , after uploading when we see at server side
 its quality is different.

All above issues we do not face when we use apache http client.

I used this code from POST [Upload Using URLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480160/how-to-upload-binary-file-using-urlconnection)

what is the benefits if we use Apache HTTP cleints for uploading ?

what is the issue if we use URLConnection to upload a binary file ?

If i use following code [Multipart Request](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/upload-files-by-sending-multipart-request-programmatically) will it work ? is there any disadvantage using this code ?

OR

anyone has a working code to upload multiple binary files sing URL Connection class using HTTP protocol.

Comment: The advantages of Apache Http Client is that it has a *much* nicer API that the equivalent classes in the JDK.  Are 7 jars really that much?  What like 1 MB.... the size of say one photo on a web page?   I recommend using it if you can. If not you can definitely make the JDK classes (URLConnection) work, just a bit more trouble.  If you go that way post about *specific* questions you have.

Comment: 7 jars is not a problem but on IE it takes 2 minutes 2 download , on chrome 1.30 minutes and on lower internet connection it takes 4 mins to download. as i said i have successfully used Apache Http Cleint in my application but the dependencies are creating problem now when loading of an applet occurs.

Answer (score 0):

This is working code for multipart buffered upload:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
int uploadBufferLength = BUFFER_DEFAULT_LENGTH;
String CRLF = "\r\n";
String boundary = (new GUID()).toString();

try
{
  java.net.URL url = new URL( DEFAULT_URL );
  connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  connection.setDoOutput( true );
  connection.setDoInput( true );
  connection.addRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary );

  for( String key : getHeaders().keySet() )
    connection.addRequestProperty( key, getHeaders().get( key ) );

  outputStreamRouter.setOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
  PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( outputStreamRouter.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8" ), true );
  writer.append( "--" ).append( boundary ).append( CRLF );
  writer.append( "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" ).append( name ).append( "\"" ).append( CRLF );
  writer.append( "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" ).append( CRLF );
  writer.append( "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" ).append( CRLF );
  writer.append( CRLF ).flush();

  //This is custom OutputStream, which should be changed to your needs or a default
  outputStreamRouter.writeStream( uploadBufferLength );
  outputStreamRouter.flush();

  writer.append( CRLF ).flush();
  writer.append( "--" ).append( boundary ).append( "--" ).append( CRLF );
  writer.close();

  outputStreamRouter.close();

  if( connection.getResponseCode() != 200 )
  {
    //handle error
  }
  else
  {
    //handle result
  }
}
catch( MalformedURLException e )
{
  throw new IllegalArgumentException( ExceptionMessage.FILE_UPLOAD_ERROR, e );
}
catch( UnsupportedEncodingException e )
{
  throw new IllegalArgumentException( ExceptionMessage.FILE_UPLOAD_ERROR, e );
}
catch( IOException e )
{
  throw new IllegalStateException( ExceptionMessage.FILE_UPLOAD_ERROR, e.getMessage() );
}
finally
{
  if( connection != null )
    connection.disconnect();
}
```

You can add more files with new boundaries.
But basically, using Apache libs will be much more easier to implement and support this code.

Comment: @Micheal thanks for it. will it work for binary files as well ? Referring to multipart do you mean that we mimic browser post upload ?

Comment: This should do well with binary files.

Comment: @Micheal i tried your code , something is missing in it. i tried http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/upload-files-by-sending-multipart-request-programmatically it is too pretty good thanks for your answer.

Comment: I told in comments, that you need your OutputStream write logic. I can post you some variant, if you need.